# Unable to establish a connection between Apache Superset and cube js using SQL API

Tags: docker, cube.js

We have deployed cube.js using docker in one of the Linux machines (Ubuntu). We have deployed Apache Superset in another Linux machine (Ubuntu). We are trying to establish a connection between "Apache Superset" and "cube.js" using SQL API, but for some reason, we are not able to establish a connection. Since cube.js and Apache superset are running on different machines, what are the values that we need to provide for the "HOST", "PORT", "DATABASE NAME", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD" in Superset when using a PostgreSQL connection?

These are the contents of the docker-compose.yml file using which cube.js is being hosted :

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  cube:
    image: cubejs/cube:latest
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 5433:5433
    environment:
      - CUBEJS_DEV_MODE=true
      - CUBEJS_DB_TYPE=bigquery
      - CUBEJS_DB_BQ_PROJECT_ID=<Our BigQuqery project ID>
      - CUBEJS_DB_BQ_KEY_FILE=<Path to Bigquery key file>
      - CUBEJS_CACHE_AND_QUEUE_DRIVER=memory
      - CUBEJS_PG_SQL_PORT=5433
      - CUBEJS_SQL_USER=test
      - CUBEJS_SQL_PASSWORD=test
     volumes:
      - ./schema:/cube/conf/schema
      - .:/cube/conf
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me is to use host.docker.internal as host in superset